# Issue handling lost Bluetooth connections using BroadcastReceiver when connected to two devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have the following code to handle lost Bluetooth connections.

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();


        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //call method to cancel connection thread
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have another app that uses Bluetooth connected to a different device running in the background.  If I lose connection to that device, I also lose the connection to the device within this app.

I was wondering, is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) you are able to get the device instance from the intent with `intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)` If the device is NOT the one you are interested in, just DO NOT call:

```
  //call method to cancel connection thread
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  I did it by checking if the address matches the device I was connected to, and if it does, cancel the connection thread.